# Trying to manipulate cronjobs using php

Tags: linux, php, cron, httpd

Good day,

Im trying to create a script to add, remove and list cronjobs inside the servers using php. Whenever I run the command like this `php cronjobs.php` the output is correct , but if i call it from inside the website, it gives back an empty result!

**Heres my code for cronjobs.php:**

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('~/cronjobs.sh');
echo "$output";
?>
```

**And here is my code for cronjob.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
crontab -l > cronjobs.log
```

Any ideas???

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try specifying full path to your script in `shell_exec` call?

Comment: @khaled yes i did , i found what the problem is , when i execute it on the command line , it shows the root cronjobs , but when i execute it on the web , it uses the "apache" user cronjobs which are none .

how can i give apache user a permission to view all the users' cronjobs ? if i run ```crontab -l -u <user>``` it gives me permission denied , so is there a way to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

> Im trying to create a script to add, remove and list cronjobs

**There are security implications** to what you are asking.

You are essentially allowing a user to run programs as anyone (even as root) on your server from a web interface via php.

**You can do it**

You could look into using `sudo` (see `man sudo` and `/etc/sudoers`) to enable apache to execute `crontab` as root. Just be really careful.